# How is the Trac Project List page customised?

Tags: trac

We've been using Trac for a while now for our developers only. However we are now opening it up for our (internal) clients. We have a project listing page (based on the default one that comes with Trac). What we'd like to do, is display more information about the project than what is currently available.

I have searched google and here, to see if I can find how to get more information. There seems to be a variable called $project which has .name, .description and .href as attributes.

Is there somewhere, a list of the attributes available? Or perhaps a different solution altogether that will allow us to display more information on the project list page. Such as the number of open tickets etc.

Comment: SuperUser is not for website support questions.  please refer to the SuperUser faq.  this seems more appropriate to Stack Overflow; your associated SO account should regain ownership automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I known, you can use $project.env as well. It is an object, which provides a number of attributes:

- $project.env.base_url
- $project.env.base_url_for_redirect
- $project.env.secure_cookies
- $project.env.project_name
- $project.env.project_description
- $project.env.project_url
- $project.env.project_admin
- $project.env.project_admin_trac_url
- $project.env.project_footer
- $project.env.project_icon
- $project.env.log_type
- $project.env.log_file
- $project.env.log_level
- $project.env.log_format

More detail is available at env.py

Answer (score 2):

On the [project page customization](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#ProjectList) page there is not much variables, indeed. Looking at the [source code](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/branches/0.11-stable/trac/web/main.py#L536) there is also trac.version, trac.time, but that's all. There is also project.env that may hold more information. I do not have a multiproject setup at hand, so you might be interested to see for yourself what variables are available with [TracDeveloper](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracDeveloperPlugin) plugin. It dumps variables if enabled and you add debug=true in the URL.